# Consuming a webhook in asp.net mvc application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, webhooks

I am learning how to consume a webhook in ASP.Net MVC solution, the webhook can be from OneDrive, GitHub or Twilio (or anyone), but I am not able to find even a basic example of consuming webhooks. I tried different keyword and searched the web but I haven't found a basic tutorial for this.

I am willing to put the controller code of my MVC Project but I don't know how to consume webhooks.

I did my research and I could not find any basic example for consuming webhooks. I am starting to wonder is there any synonym terms for webhooks I should be entering into a search engine?

Links I looked into: [VS Hooks](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2015/09/29/announcing-the-asp-net-webhooks-visual-studio-extension-preview/)

Comment: It may help https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/g_arora/getting-started-with-microsoft-Asp-Net-webhook/

Comment: To listen a webhook you basically need a controller with some method that allows HttpPost request. The system who fires the webhook must have some doc/config to know method name and params. Usually you need a DNS or public ip to get the request

Comment: @Mate: Can I have consume a webhook on localhost coming from some thirdparty?

Comment: Yes, using something like https://ngrok.com/

Comment: @Mate: Thank you so much, I will try. :)

Comment: Great. Let us know your results

Comment: @Mate I can’t tell you how happy I am, I was able to consume the web hook. Just created basic api end point used ngrok and it was hitting the VS breakpoint. So yeah!! I successfully consumed the third party web hook. Thank you so so much!

Comment: Good Job! I'm glad you solved it

Answer (score 0):

To listen a webhook you basically need a controller with some method that allows HttpPost request. The system who fires the webhook must have some doc/config to know method name and params. Usually you need a DNS or public ip to get the request

@Mate already answered this using example from https://ngrok.com/